# Writing better selector in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

What would be the best way to write the following selector?

```
id = "#id",
$id = $("#id");
//works but seems wrong    
$($id, 'a').click(function(){
 //do stuff..
});

//this was not working for me.
$id.find('a').click(function(){
 // do stuff...
});
```

Comment: Are you sure there is no `.` before the 2nd `click`?

Comment: @KennyTM, there is a .  sorry just edited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the proper syntax for the shorter find is:

```
$('a', $id).click(function(){
 //do stuff..
});
```

this finds all anchor tags within `$id`

to use it with the find fn:

```
$id.find('a').click(function(){
 // do stuff...
});
```

this is all under the assumption that ur markup is like so:

```
<div id='id'> //div or any other html element
    ... any code
    <a href.... ></a> << the anchor can be anywhere inside this div
</div>
```

Comment: this finds all anchor tags with $id

It sounds strange, because id should be unique, according to (X)HTML specification.

Comment: @Marcin i meant to write `within` i fixed it

Answer (score 1):

The context [is the second argument](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1), not the first.

```
$('a', '#id').click(function(){
 //do stuff..
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#id a").click(function() {} );
```

or

```
$("#id > a").click(function() {} );
```

Comment: lets us say the anchor tag is not located directly inside the `#id` than this wont work...

Comment: +1 first option is the best suggestion. Second is not equivalent to what the OP is asking though ..